# Rails paperclip plugin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie. I am trying to upload an image through paperclip. The url and path code is working but the style option is not working. This is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file   :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                      :url  => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

When I use the style it doesn't work. If I remove the style option it does work. Please help me out!

Comment: Can you post any error messages you are getting from the log?

Comment: an alternative to paperclip is carrierwave.

Comment: I thought ImageMajick and RMajick were required to let Paperclip do thumbnailing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try `:style_:basename.:extension`

Comment: Thanx Julian but i'm not talking about the style in url, i give emphasise on :style=>{:small=>"150x150">},actully this code is not working ..........